# php zend framework gmail - how to get messages from specific interval?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using the Zend Framework and again there is something I cannot figure out.
How do I make parameters for fetching messages in a given time interval, something like the last 24 hours or so?

At the moment I get all messages from inbox and sent messages, but I do not want all as it gives a lot of traffic.

There must be some sort of parameter that has to be set somewhere, I just cant seem to figure out where. the mails are from Gmail

It is the standard Zend framework that I use in php (no modifications to the framework).

```
public function fetchmails($imap)
    {
    global $smarty; 
    //arrays to store mails and data
    $mailarray = null;
    $maildataarray = null;
    $box = null;
     $storage = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap($imap);
    // echo "<pre>";
     //var_dump($storage->getFolders());

     for ($j = 1; $j <= 2; $j++)
     {
     if($j==1)
     {
      $storage->selectFolder("INBOX");
      $box = "Inbox";

     }
     if($j==2)
     {
     $storage->selectFolder("[Gmail]/Sendte e-mails");
     $box = "Outbox";
     }
     $antal = $storage->countMessages();
```

this code executes code in the zend framework

Comment: Fetching which messages?

Comment: gmail messages. sorry for not writing that

Comment: How are you fetching them? Have you written any code? Can you share that with us?

Comment: there is a little bit there... it must be the zend that is the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$antal = $imap->search(array('SINCE 22-May-2014'));
```

That was the thing I needed

antal is danish and means number of... it actually only gets the ids of the messages that is in the search... just so you all know.